# How to turn 4 bytes into a float in objective-c from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is an example of turning 4 bytes into a 32bit integer in objective-c. The function **readInt** grabs 4 bytes from the **read** function and then converts it into a single 32 bit int. Does anyone know how I would convert 4 bytes to a float? I believe it is big endian. Basically I need a readFloat function. I can never grasp these bitwise operations.

**EDIT:**
**I forgot to mention that the original data comes from Java's DataOutputStream class. The writeFloat function accordign to java doc is**

> Converts the float argument to an int using the floatToIntBits method
>   in class Float, and then writes that int value to the underlying
>   output stream as a 4-byte quantity, high byte first.

This is Objective c trying to extract the data written by java.

```
- (int32_t)read{
    int8_t v;
    [data getBytes:&v range:NSMakeRange(length,1)];
    length++;
    return ((int32_t)v & 0x0ff);
}

- (int32_t)readInt {
    int32_t ch1 = [self read];
    int32_t ch2 = [self read];
    int32_t ch3 = [self read];
    int32_t ch4 = [self read];
    if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0){
        @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"Exception" reason:@"EOFException" userInfo:nil];
    }
    return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
}
```

Comment: You need to know the representation of the float in the bytes. Where does this data come from? Is there a spec or similar documentation for the data source or protocol?

Comment: @KenThomases It comes from Java's DataOutputStream class. I'm trying to read it in through ios.

Answer (score 2):

[OSByteOrder.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/libkern/libkern/OSByteOrder.h) contains functions for reading, writing, and converting integer data.

You can use `OSSwapBigToHostInt32()` to convert a big-endian integer to the native representation, then copy the bits into a float:

```
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/java/test.dat"];

    int32_t bytes;
    [data getBytes:&bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];

    bytes = OSSwapBigToHostInt32(bytes);

    float number;
    memcpy(&number, &bytes, sizeof(bytes));

    NSLog(@"Float %f", number);
```

Answer (score 1):

`[data getBytes:&myFloat range:NSMakeRange(locationWhereFloatStarts, sizeof(float)]` ought to do the trick.

Comment: I tried, I think it needs to be converted to big endian

Answer (score 1):

Given that the data comes from `DataOutputStream`'s [`writeFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeFloat%28float%29) method, then that is documented to use [`Float.floatToIntBits()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29) to create the integer representation. [`intBitsToFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) further documents how to interpret that representation.

I'm not sure if it's the same thing, but the `xdr` API seems like it might handle that representation. The credits on the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/xdr.3.html) refer to Sun Microsystems standards/specifications, so it seems likely it's related to Java.

So, it may work to do something like:

```
// At top of file:
#include <rpc/types.h>
#include <rpc/xdr.h>

// In some function or method:
XDR xdr;
xdrmem_create(&xdr, (char*)data.bytes + offset, data.length - offset, XDR_DECODE);
float f;
if (!xdr_float(&xdr, &f))
    /* handle error */;
xdr_destroy(&xdr);
```

If the data consists of a whole stream in eXternal Data Representation, then you would create one XDR stream for the whole task of extracting items from it, and use many `xdr_...()` calls between creating and destroying it to extract all of the items.